# Inject a field in JSON Serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am looking to inject a field into the JSON I am serializing from a POJO.  I am using Jackson to perform the serialization and I can create a customer serializer to inject the field.  What I have so far is:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Child newChild = new Child();
        newChild.setName("John");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("Custom Child Serializer", new Version(1,0,0,null));
        module.addSerializer(new CustomChildSerializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(newChild));
        System.in.read();
    }
}

class CustomChildSerializer extends SerializerBase<Child> {
    public CustomChildSerializer() {
        super(Child.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Child child, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("Name", child.getName());
        jgen.writeStringField("Injected Value","Value");
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}

class Child {
    private String Name;
    public String getName() { return Name; }
    public void setName(String name) {  Name = name; }
}
```

Assuming that `Child` is a class that is part of an API and I cannot modify it.  Is there a way I can modify the custom serializer to use the default serialization for the `Child` class, so that when `Child` changes, I do not have to modify the custom serializer?

Comment: Why are you using a custom serializer, in the exmaple it seems that you could simply use the object mapper without the Custom Serializer. If you are trying to solve some more complex problem and you can't modify the Child object to say add annotations. You can use the jackson mixins to add serialization parameters without having to manually serialize the object.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw My understanding is that Mixins do not support adding fields but rather mapping existing data.  I cannot modify the `Child` class in this case as it is data coming back to me from an external API.

Comment: Which version of Jackson are you using? Could you use the newest one - 2.2.3?

Comment: @MichałZiober I am on 1.9.13.  I could probably move to 2.2.3 if it would address the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert object to `Map` add additional properties and serialize full map. See below serializer:

```
class CustomChildSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Child> {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MapType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, String.class);

    @Override
    public void serialize(Child child, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
        Map<String, String> map = mapper.convertValue(child, type);
        map.put("Injected Value", "Value");

        jgen.writeObject(map);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Child> handledType() {
        return Child.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: My example uses 2.2.3 version. Maybe oldest versions do not support this feature. I do not know. I have never used oldest version of this library. Maybe you need add additional annotations/ObjectMapper configuration to enable this feature. It it is not a problem I suggest to use the newest version of Jackson.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't notice it. I have changed my answer.